# mysql query to find value which repeats for maximum time

Tags: mysql

I need to find value in `b_id` which repeats for maximum time. for example query for the table below should return 40 (n.b., query should return a single value)

```
| b_id | s_id | doi        | dos        | charge |
+------+------+------------+------------+--------+
|   10 |    3 | 0000-00-00 | 0000-00-00 |    200 |
|   10 |    2 | 0000-00-00 | 0000-00-00 |    200 |
|   20 |    1 | 0000-00-00 | 0000-00-00 |    200 |
|   30 |    2 | 0000-00-00 | 0000-00-00 |    200 |
|   40 |    4 | 0000-00-00 | 0000-00-00 |    200 |
|   40 |    5 | 0000-00-00 | 0000-00-00 |    200 |
|   70 |    5 | 0000-00-00 | 0000-00-00 |    200 |
|   40 |    4 | 0000-00-00 | 0000-00-00 |    200 |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT TOP 1 COUNT(*) as total FROM dbo.Table GROUP BY b_id ORDER BY total DESC
```

edit:
ups, mysql equivalent:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as total FROM dbo.Table GROUP BY b_id ORDER BY total DESC LIMIT 1
```

edit2:
after the comment:

```
SELECT b_id FROM dbo.Table GROUP BY b_id ORDER BY COUNT(b_id) DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Problem is i just want to return 40...nothing else...not even the counted value...

Comment: ok, sorry, I haven't understood the question properly. I updated my answer.